# Need help on oracle query format

Tags: oracle11g

I need help on setting the format for SQL output.
for ex. I have this below query which gives the following result:

`SQL> select instance_name,status from v$instance;`

```
INSTANCE_NAME    STATUS
---------------- ------------
isorcl1          OPEN
```

But I want the output to be in the format something like below, can you please help!
Thanks in advance!

`SQL> select instance_name,status from v$instance;`

```
INSTANCE_NAME      ISORCL1   
STATUS             OPEN
```

Comment: That is not possible in sqlplus. You have to copy the ouput and use Notepad++ etc and manually remove those lines

Answer (score 1):

Ugly but it works for the OP's example; Mask the header and run this query in sqlplus

```
SET HEADING OFF;

SELECT 'INSTANCE_NAME', instance_name FROM v$instance
UNION ALL
SELECT 'STATUS', status FROM v$instance;
```

Comment: You will still get ------------ in output